# What are the differences between throwaway and evolutionary prototypes?

Tags: prototyping, specifications

I have notes about various methods of prototyping, and I found several definitions on the Internet, but I would like to confirm what I learned.

I understand that **throwaway prototyping** is developed from an outline of a specification, an various prototypes are delivered and modified until the client is satisfied with its functionality.

On the other and, **evolutionary prototypes** are built from basic requirements gathered from end-users. An initial prototype is presented to the users and evaluated. The prototype is modified based on the feedback until the client is satisfied.

Is this correct? Are there better definitions of throwaway and evolutionary prototyping?

Comment: More often then not it seems that the prototype evolves into the finished product.  Never really heard of the throwaway versus evolutionary before.

Comment: Hi Mifas, I'm sorry this got migrated, but if you got your definitions from the web, asking the web to confirm if the definitions are correct is circular and not really on-topic here.

Comment: @MarkTrapp If we removed the definitions, could we reopen? Both the definitions in the post as well as the existing answer are wrong in terms of the formal definition of the phrase. There are duplicates on Stack Overflow, but none that I can find here and I think it's essential to, at the very least, not put more false information on the Internet.

Comment: @Mifas If you remove the definitions, there's no body to the question, is there? If Mifas were to follow the question here and update it to explain what he's trying to do that's got him asking about these definitions, that'd be a perfectly fine question.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Then deletion should happen unless someone else can improve the question beyond my edit, since there isn't a question without confirming the definitions. Every definition here (question and answer) is wrong per McConnell's Rapid Development and (as I just checked) Sommerville's Software Engineering (8th Edition). Leaving it is spreading false information.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Sold and reopened.

Comment: @Mark Fantastic. Thanks. Working on my answer now.

Comment: @Mark If you feel this is a bad question still, feel free to close (and make my answer a wiki as well, if that's necessary - I don't give a damn about the rep). I just feel better knowing that the correct information is on the Internet and people who read this question from Google won't see wrong. (Yes, I did another of my SOMEONE IS WRONG ON THE INTERNET!!! moments, but it's all good now.) Thanks a ton.

Comment: Evolutionary prototypes are the Throwaway prototypes that evolved and survived.

Answer (score 12):

Both methods of prototyping are used when there's some aspect of the system that you don't entirely understand. However, the key difference is the lifecycle methodology that you use. With evolutionary prototyping, you typically understand some aspects of the system and aren't sure about others. In throwaway prototyping, you have a general lack of understanding that you need to complete before you can build a production-ready system.

Note that there are lots of kinds of throwaway prototyping, and neither are limited to the entire system. For example, using paper or whiteboard sketches of a user interface can be considered throwaway prototyping. Yes, you might go through several iterations and throw away a previous design, but you also won't use the final prototype in the system (it's not physically possible, for one).

If you're interested in general software engineering topics and the breadth of SE, I'd highly suggest picking up the Sommerville book that I quote. It's really good for covering the breadth of topics. If you're more interested in process models and methodologies and how you can apply them to various projects, I'd recommend the McConnell book - it has an entire chapter devoted to evolutionary prototyping and another chapter devoted to throwaway prototyping.

I also took a quick glance at the [Wikipedia article on software prototyping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_prototyping). Some parts of it are a little weird (at least on my quick read), but there doesn't appear to be anything that I downright disagree with. Some of it is a little focused on one particular aspect, but it's not factually wrong that I see. I prefer the definitions below, but it might be an interesting read on various types of prototyping.

---

## Evolutionary Prototyping

> Exploratory development where the objective of the process is to work
>   with the customer to explore their requirements and deliver a final
>   system. The development starts with the parts of the system that are
>   understood. The system evolves by adding new features proposed by the
>   customer. [(Sommerville: Software Engineering, 8th Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321313798)

---

> Evolutionary Prototyping is a lifecycle model in which the system is
>   developed in increments so that it can readily be modified in response
>   to end-user and customer feedback. Most evolutionary-prototyping
>   efforts begin by prototyping the user interface and then evolving the
>   completed system from that, but prototyping can start with any
>   high-risk area. Evolutionary Prototyping is not the same as Throwaway
>   Prototyping, and making the right choice about whether to develop an
>   evolutionary prototype or a throwaway prototype is one key to success.
>   Other keys to success include using experienced developers, managing
>   schedule and budget expectations, and managing the prototyping
>   activity itself. [(McConnell: Rapid Development: Taming Wild Software Schedules)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1556159005)

---

## Throwaway Prototyping:

> Throwaway prototyping is where the objective of the evolutionary
>   development process is to understand the customer's requirements and
>   hence develop a better requirements definition for the system. The
>   prototype concentrates on experimenting with the customer requirements
>   that are poorly understood. [(Sommerville: Software Engineering, 8th
>   Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321313798)

---

> With Throwaway Prototyping, code is developed to explore factors
>   critical to the system's success, and then that code is thrown away.
>   The prototyping implementation uses programming languages or
>   development practices or both that are much faster than the target
>   language and practices. The user interface is prototyped far more
>   commonly than any other part of the system, but other parts of some
>   systems can also benefit from being prototyped. When used as a
>   requirementsspecification aid, the Throwaway Prototyping practice can
>   accelerate projects based on traditional lifecycle models, such as DoD
>   projects. It can be initiated at either a management or technical
>   level. [(McConnell: Rapid Development: Taming Wild Software Schedules)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1556159005)

Answer (score -2):

Throwaway prototyping - with this a small part of the system is developed and then given to the customers and end users to try and evaluate it.The user provides the feedback which can quickly be inco-operated into the development of the main system

Evolutionary Prototyping - is a life cycle model in which the System is developed in increments so that it can readily be modified in response to end users and Customer feedback

Comment: This question was asked in 2011. You answer does not add much to the answers already given.